# Windows case sensitivity causing trouble, Can't include a Java project to Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, case-sensitive

so I decompiled one of my jars, and in the nature of decompilers, it named the classes from a to z. After one cycle it started naming them the same again, but with captioned letters, so I might end up having a.java and A.java in the final zip file.

This is when the problem comes in, as I can't extract the zip anywhere because windows goes all retarded after trying to extract a.java and A.java to the same directory

Any ideas?

Comment: How about Linux?  :-)

Comment: Would work, I actually have it on my laptop, but I'm hoping to get a solution to this with on my Windows. Something like opening the source directly from the .zip file or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redo the decompilation. As this is a common problem that is not unique to you, there should be a way to make the decompiler use other names.

If that does not work, you can easily extract your files by simply doing it in two steps: One time extract only the upper case files, move them into a subfolder, then extract the remaining files. Afterwards import everything into Eclipse and use "Organize imports" to fix all the imports to the moved uppercase files. Alternatively you could use two different source directories to organize your two sets of files.

There is absolutely no way, you can import the original zip into Eclipse. An Eclipse workspace contains resources which are mapped to files on the underlying file system. Therefore all restrictions of the file system apply, and you cannot have a.java and A.java in the identical package.

Answer (score 2):

This is a porting problem that there is *no* good way around.  What you can do, if you don't actually care about the names of the file is to rename them inside the zip.  Winzip lets you do this; I'm sure other tools do, as well.

Comment: This would be a good idea, but I'm not too sure if winzip lets me rename all the code references as well.